How to detect changes in the UserControl informing about the need to save?
I have UserControl which contains many controls: gridControl, treeList, textEdit, spinEdit, e.t.c.
I have two objects: first is downloaded from database and second is his copy on which I work. I have method which comparing this objects before saving and if there is some differences saving to database. How can I detect differences on some event to inform User for example some message or icon? Maybe is better way than event to detect differences?
I think adding method to every control or cell value changed is not good way....???
I am using control.dataBinding and for example I don't need event value changed so this is not good way I think and there is to many controls.

if you load data into dataset and then use data binding objects, when you make changes dataset keeps new and old values that you can query later. write by hand? possible! Memento pattern. you take original object, make a copy, let it be modified. Then in the end, compare it to your memento

Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface on your data model. Then you can subscribe a single event in your data model instead of on all the controls. Take care to bind with OnPropertyChanged and not OnValidation in the Data / DataBindings / Advanced properties.
Then you can compare the edited object to the old object every time the PropertyChanged event fires.
There is yet another advantage in doing so. If you change the value of a model property in code, the PropertyChanged event informs the UI that a values has changed, and the display is updated automatically.
